# Sending automated Email in Titanium mobile

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I'm working on a project where, I need to send emails with some predefined messages. Titanium Mobile offers sending email through Titanium.UI.EmailDilog. But this does not fit to my requirements. I need to send email without displaying a dialog to user. If anybody have a solution to this, please tell.

Answer (score 0):

You cant send emails using native API's without user consent (on iOS or Android). The only way to do it is with the native dialog.  I'm pretty sure this is in place because Apple doesnt want you spamming on behalf of the user. For android the answer is the same, at least with Titanium.

If you really want to do this you have two options as I see it, write a webservice that sends emails on your behalf, and let the mobile app call it.  Or wrap a library such as [SKPMTPMessage for iOS](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) to send messages programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it on the device using Titanium Mobile, but you can try using Appcelerator Cloud Services (ACS) to send it.  See [Cloud.Email](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Cloud.Emails)

Answer (score 0):

What are your requirements exactly? Is it sending predefined (transactional?) email *to* the user's inbox or on *behalf* of the user to a 3rd party?
For a simple solution (for verify user e-mail, password reset, etc.) I'd say Parse. An example from Parse for sending Password Reset e-mails:

> You can initiate password resets for users who have emails associated
>   with their account. To do this, send a POST request to
>   /1/requestPasswordReset endpoint with email in the body of the
>   request:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"email":"coolguy@iloveapps.com"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/requestPasswordReset
```

source: [Parse Documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#users-password-reset)

For more custom transactional emails there is [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) (powered by Mailchimp)

Does any of that fit the bill?